# Making separate pages for item, PHP

Tags: php

I have a database of store names, and I want to make it possible that each store has its own personal page.

Would I have to make a separate page for each store or is there a way to have a single page that works as a template that when the user clicks on the store name the information just changes according to the store name.

If so could someone please set me in the right direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's kind of the most basic use of PHP and databases. Maybe a PHP/MySQL tutorial would be a good start?

Comment: Start working on it on your own and come back when you have a more specific problem. Voting to close for now.

Comment: I will look into a tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible to do this:

```
<?php
$store = 'abc'; // here make $store equal the store name out from the database

echo "Welcome to ".$store."'s store!";

?>
```

You could include further items, or even have images from the stores folder by using the $store variable as well. For example, to show the logo you could do the following:

```
<?php
echo "<img src=\"http://www.domain.com/".$store."/logo.jpg\">";
?>
```

At the end of the day, it depends how complex you want it. But as others will say, you'd better learn some of PHP's functionality and database features so you can get the result that you need.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. I just needed a to see that.

Comment: Not necessarily open to XSS - @Eric you should ensure that you sanitize any input database queries as well as checking that the store name is correct and nothing else. If you do everything correctly, then you won't have many/any problems.

Comment: Hey, I got it to echo "Welcome to ...'s Store" But I was wondering how it would be done if I want the stores name to be the grabbed from the database? thank you